# How to access only Y coordinates of CGPoints in array?

Tags: arrays, macos, swift2, cgpoint

I've got an array of 20 CGPoints. How to access just Y coordinates of every CGPoint in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrayOfPoints : [CGPoint] = [.....]//your array of points

for point in arrayOfPoints {
   let y = point.y
   //You now have just the y coordinate of each point in the array.
}
```

Or if you are using `.enumerate()` syntax.

```
for (index, point) in arrayOfPoints.enumerate() {
   let y = point.y
   //You now have just the y coordinate of each point in the array.

   print(point.y) //Prints y coordinate of each point.
}
```

Swift makes common `for` loop operations simple. For example,
If you want an array of all the y coordinates then you can use a nice one liner in swift.

```
let arrayOfYCoordinates : [CGFloat] = arrayOfPoints.map { $0.y }
```

Or pass in to pass each y coordiante to the same function.

```
arrayOfPoints.map { myFunction($0.y) }
```

Comment: Ok. I tried to access Y coordinates through this code:

for (index, point) in arrayOfPoints.enumerate() {
}

But it doesn't work for me. What is wrong?

Comment: Using `.enumerate()` syntax, `index` is the position your `CGPoint` is in the array of `CGPoints`, while `point` would be that instance of `CGPoint` in your array. So you would access the y coordinate by writing `point.y`

Comment: @Swift I'll update my answer with `.enumerate` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
let arrayOfPoints : [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 3, y: 4)]

let yCoordinates = arrayOfPoints.map { $0.y }

for y in yCoordinates {
    print("y = \(y)") //Or whatever you want to do with the y coordinates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why won't a simple foreach loop with `point.y` work?